# Local File Path does not work in my html file

Tags: python, flask

I'm working on a flask app, and the problem that I'm struggling now is that any local path doesn't seem to work within the html file
The structure is like this:

`Code/app.py`
`Code/enternew.html`
`Code/one.jpg`
`Code/styles.css`

and right now in my html file, I'm trying to load the css file and images in using
`<link type="text/css" href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet"/>`
and
`<img src="one.jpg" >`

but neither works

alternatively if I copy the css code to  in the  part it works, if I use an online picture it also works, such as `<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/picture.jpg">`

but if i use a local path nothing seems to load. Does anyone have any idea what could be the issue? thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can't link static files from the root directory like that.
By default Flask will set up `./static` as the directory from which to serve files from.
Just like it sets up .`/templates` directory to look for templates.

Make a folder called static on your app directory and move your files there. Then link them with `href="static/<your_file>"`.

Have a look at the project layout that Flask proposes here -> https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/tutorial/layout/